# How to use columns added later on select as query in MYSQL when joining to another table

Tags: mysql, join

I get unknown column error from this query. How can I use such queries?

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN(c.from_user=144) 
        THEN c.to_user 
        ELSE c.from_user 
    END) as chatted_to 
FROM `chat_message` `c` 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON chatted_to = user.id 
WHERE (`to_user`=144) OR (`from_user`=144) 
GROUP BY `chatted_to`
```

It says:

> Unknown column 'chatted_to' in 'on clause'.

Comment: Can't you just repeat the `CASE` portion again when using `ON chatted_to=user.id`: `ON (case when(c.from_user=144) then c.to_user else c.from_user END)=user.id`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the `CASE` condition again in the `ON` clause, like this:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN(c.from_user=144) THEN c.to_user 
        ELSE c.from_user 
    END) as chatted_to 
FROM `chat_message` `c` 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON 
    (CASE 
        WHEN(c.from_user=144) THEN c.to_user 
        ELSE c.from_user 
    END) = user.id 
WHERE (`to_user`=144) OR (`from_user`=144) 
GROUP BY `chatted_to`
```